# Split a list at the first occurrence of an element

Tags: haskell

I was wondering if there is a function that lets me split a list at the first occurrence of an element, excluding that element. Basically, suppose:

```
listT= [1,3,2,5,6,3,2,6]
```

then I want to define (or not, if it already exists), a function splitAtFirst so that

```
splitAtFirst 2 listT = [[1,3],[5,6,3,2,6]]
```

my attempt so far looks like this:

```
splitAtfirst::(Eq a)=> a->[a]->[[a]]
splitAtfirst _ []=[]
splitAtfirst a (x:xs) 
   |a==x        = [xs]
   |otherwise   = [x]: splitAtfirst a (xs)
```

However, I get

```
>splitAtfirst 2 [1,3,2,5,6,3,2,6]
>[[1],[3],[5,6,3,2,6]]
```

I know why the problem happens, but so far I haven't been able to find a good solution

I appreciate any help!

Edit: this is an auxiliary function that only will be called after checking that elem is in the list, so dealing with the case when it does not exist it's not really necessary. I appreciate your help

Comment: Some observations: (1) The hint in dfeuer's answer is indeed decisive. (2) Note that you aren't actually building the first list with the values before the split point. (3) Style nitpicking: the parentheses around `xs` in your `otherwise` case are superfluous and should be dropped.

Comment: Note on your edit point: it seems unlikely to be efficient to first check that the element is in the list and then split it there. The process of checking if an element is in a list can be expensive; it's usually a good idea to "hold the place" where you found it. If you show how this function fits in context, we will probably be able to help more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have committed to the wrong result type, which is preventing the type checker from helping you as much as it could. You say you want

```
splitAtFirst 2 listT = [[1,3],[5,6,3,2,6]]
```

This pins you to

```
splitAtfirst::(Eq a)=> a->[a]->[[a]]
```

which allows the list to be split into arbitrarily many lists.

But in fact you want to split the list into *two*. One point you don't address in your question is what you want the result to be if I ask something like `splitAtFirst 2 [1,3]`, where the element is not found. There are three options that seem reasonable:

```
splitAtFirst :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Maybe ([a],[a])
-- splitAtFirst 2 [1,3] = Nothing

splitAtFirst :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> ([a],[a])
-- splitAtFirst 2 [1,3] = ([1,3],[])

splitAtFirst :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> ([a], Maybe [a])
-- splitAtFirst 2 [1,3] = ([1,3],Nothing)
```

Note that I did not suggest

```
-- splitAtFirst 2 [1,3] = ([], [1,3])
```

The reason has to do with laziness and efficiency—can you figure out why? The first `Maybe` version also has this potential problem, but it makes up for it by being more useful.

Once you commit to one of these options, you will likely find it easier to get the implementation right.

Answer (score 9):

Since dfeuer has already pointed the way towards fixing your implementation, I will just chime in with the ready-made solution:

```
splitAtFirst :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
splitAtFirst x = fmap (drop 1) . break (x ==)
```

This `splitAtFirst` implements the second option from the three suggestions in dfeuer's answer. A few notes on each of the components:

- `(x ==)` is a function which tests for equality with `x`, returning a `Bool`.
- [`break`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:break) uses a boolean test (here, `(x ==)`) to break a list in two, the second list beginning with the first element that passes the test. The two lists are returned as a pair (see dfeuer's answer for the reason why it is so).
- `drop 1` drops the first element of a list if it is not empty (and leaves it alone if it is empty).
- `fmap` would take quite a bit longer to explain properly, so I will just say that `fmap f` applied on a pair (such as the result of `break`) applies the function `f` to the second element of the pair. In our case, `fmap (drop 1)` will remove the first element of the second list -- that is, the separator. (To find out more about `fmap`, search for the keyword "functor", or just try using it on a list or a `Maybe`-value and see what happens.)

Comment: I find `(id *** drop 1)` clearer than `fmap` in these sorts of jobs.

Comment: @pigworker A fair point. Here, I considered using `second` instead of `fmap` for the reason you mention. I settled on `fmap` mainly because it seemed possible that the OP hadn't been introduced to either of them, and in such a case a first encounter with `Functor` would perhaps be more fruitful than one with `Bifucntor` or `Arrow`.